# how to remove one part of the getting id

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi i have some div having id newvalue1,newvalue2,........when i click any of this

```html
<div id="newvalue1"></div>
<div id="newvalue2"></div>
<div id="newvalue3"></div>
<div id="newvalue4"></div>
```

div i want get the one part of the id for example if i click the div newvalue1 i

want 1 in a variable if i click newvalue2 i want 2 in that variable

Comment: `$('[id^="newvalue"]').click(function () { alert(this.id.match(/\d+$/)[0]);  });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, this example shows you how to do that.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
.square{
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 border: 2px solid black;
 margin: 10px;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 20px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
</style>


<body>

<div id="newvalue1" class="square" style="background-color:orange">one</div>
<div id="newvalue2" class="square" style="background-color:red">two</div>
<div id="newvalue3" class="square" style="background-color:pink">three</div>
<div id="newvalue4" class="square" style="background-color:purple">four</div>
<div id="newvalue5" class="square" style="background-color:blue">five</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
 $(".square").click(function(){
  var theid = $(this).attr('id');
  var integerval = theid.replace( /[^\d.]/g,'');
  alert(theid);
  alert(integerval);

  //inteterval will give you the nlumber.
 });
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks "id.replace( /[^\d.]/g,'');"is realy usable one

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
function test(t){
var v = t.id.split('newvalue');
console.log(v[1]);
}
```

```html
<div id="newvalue1" onclick="test(this)">1</div>
<div id="newvalue2" onclick="test(this)">2</div>
<div id="newvalue3" onclick="test(this)">3</div>
<div id="newvalue4" onclick="test(this)">4</div>
```